# Checking if two People share the same phone number in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table which contains StudentIDs and Phone Numbers.. Some students share the same Phone Number, and I want to select and display those students.

For example.

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| StudentID | StudentID | PNumber      |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|      1000 |      1000 | 970-555-1000 |
|      1000 |      1000 | 970-555-1010 |
|      1100 |      1100 | 970-555-1100 |
|      1200 |      1200 | 303-555-1200 |
|      1200 |      1300 | 303-555-1200 |
|      1300 |      1200 | 303-555-1200 |
|      1300 |      1300 | 303-555-1200 |
|      1300 |      1300 | 303-555-1210 |
|      1400 |      1400 | 970-555-1400 |
|      1500 |      1500 | None         |
|      1600 |      1600 | 970-555-1600 |
|      1600 |      1700 | 970-555-1600 |
|      1700 |      1600 | 970-555-1600 |
|      1700 |      1700 | 970-555-1600 |
|      1800 |      1800 | 970-555-1800 |
|      1900 |      1900 | 970-555-1900 |
|      2000 |      2000 | 970-555-2000 |
|      2000 |      2000 | 970-555-2010 |
|      2001 |      2001 | 970-555-2001 |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

This should output:

```
1200 | 1300 | 303-555-1200
1300 | 1200 | 303-555-1200
1600 | 1700 | 970-555-1600
1700 | 1600 | 970-555-1600
```

Comment: Why does your input have two columns with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try join itself:

```
select t1.StudentID,t2.StudentID,t1.PNumber
from Student t1
join Student t2 on t1.PNumber= t2.PNumber
where t1.StudentID <> t2.StudentID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a self JOIN:

```
SELECT
    s1.StudentID, s2.StudentID, s1.PNumber
FROM
    students s1 INNTER JOIN students s2 USING(StudentID)
WHERE s1.PNumber = p2.PNumber;
```

Comment: So I had your exact same code with out the self JOIN. This is basically joining the table to its self?

Comment: Yes. Joining with itself.